# Action on bluetooth error connection in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am building an android app that connects through bluetooth to an Arduino board. I have managed to connect and send data. In the first activity, I list all the paired devices and the available devices and when I click on one of them, if it is available, it connects to the board but if it is not available (click on a paired devices but this one is not near or has the bluetooth deactivated) the app shows a dialog to indicate that the device is trying to connect and it cannot be dismissed. Is there any event which is triggered when the mobile cannot connect to the device selected?
I have thought that this could be accomplished by setting a timer to dismiss the dialog, in that case, how can I stop the ongoing connection attempt? I have been looking for a couple of days and the only solutions I have found are related to the disconnection and state changed events. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```
public void setOnDiscoveryListener(final OnDiscoveryListener listener){
    oldReceiver = receiver;
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            switch (action){
                case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED:
                listener.onStartDiscovery();
                break;

                case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED:
                listener.onStopDiscovery();
                break;

                case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND:
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                listener.onDeviceDiscovery(device);
                break;

                case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED:
                listener.onDeviceConnected();
                break;

                case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED:
                listener.onDeviceDisconnected();
                break;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I use an interface to initialize the broadcast receiver.

```
bluetoothManager.setOnDiscoveryListener(new BluetoothManager.OnDiscoveryListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStartDiscovery() { }

    @Override
    public void onStopDiscovery() {
        progressBar.hide();
        refreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
        bluetoothManager.updateOnDiscoveryListener(discoveryListener);
        if(noAvailableDevices)
            noAvailableDevicesText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeviceDiscovery(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
        noAvailableDevices = false;
        availableDevicesAdapter.addDevice(new Device(bluetoothDevice.getName(), bluetoothDevice.getAddress()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeviceConnected() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MenuActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeviceDisconnected() { }
});
```

Finally, I use these filters.

```
bluetoothManager.setDiscoveryFilters(activity, new String[]{
    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED,
    BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED,
    BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND,
    BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED,
    BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED});
```

This is the code for the **OnClick** event of the list items.

```
private View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String deviceName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name)).getText().toString();
        String deviceAddress = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address)).getText().toString();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog
            .show(activity, null, getResources().getString(R.string.connecting) + " " + deviceName, true);

        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, BluetoothService.class);
        intent.putExtra(Constants.MAC_KEY, deviceAddress);
        activity.startService(intent);
    }
};
```

Comment: Pls post your code here - API s you are calling to initialize..connect etc

Comment: I've posted my code. Thanks.

Comment: Using debugger/logs do you see `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED:` being hit ?

Comment: Am assuming you are having adequate manifest permissions : ` "android.permission.BLUETOOTH"`

Comment: Also post the code where you click a paired device and it attempts to connect

Comment: I have no problem with the connection. What I want to do is to listen to an event that is triggered when it is not possible to connect to a selected devices because this has not activated the bluetooth or is not near enough to the mobile to detect it. In other words, if it is not possible to connect to the device, I want to show an alert that says "There has been an error while trying to connect." and stop the attempt to connect. And yes, the event **BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED** is hit and I have the proper permissions in the manifest.

Comment: Your connect API would have call back registrations indicating async timeout.. if it's a sync failure then you don't have to draw the connecting dialog - else dismiss the dialog from the async callback showing the error msg

Comment: Another approach would be to check in `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED` if the said UUID is retrieved after discovery times out .. that's when you can dismiss the connecting dialog

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the last comment, the UUID that I used is fixed, I don't retrieve it from the bluetooth API. I'll try to dismiss the dialog after the bluetooth socket timeout.

Comment: OK I thought you started from scan ..  Actually this will be a good idea - under the hood when connect is pressed do a scan to see if the UUID is returned - if no you know it's not going to connect and you can dismiss the popup - that way you don;t even have to attempt to connect

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let me know if this strategy works for you - will post this as an ans then..

Comment: Showing the message after the **BluetoothSocket** timeout works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing discussion in comments as an ans:-

At the radio layer every interaction with the remote device is **asynchronous** Hence you should get callback from the underlying Android FW against call to *connect()*

In case you are not receiving async connect failure call backs - another strategy would be to start a scan in `OnClick()` and match the device (Bluetooth Device Addr/ MAC) in scan callback with your saved device. Connect will definitely fail if scan fails to return this device ID. That's when you can clean up the progress bar.

Having said that there will be an odd case when the device is in range and is discovered in scan but fails to connect due to some other reason, you will have to handle the failure cb in this case